# Cast generic return type into lambda expression

Tags: java, generics, bounded-wildcard

I use this lambda expression to find a nested object

```
Optional<? extends OnlineResource> onlineResourceOptional =
        metadata.getDistributionInfo().stream()
                .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                .flatMap(distribution -> distribution.getTransferOptions().stream())
                .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                .flatMap(digitalTransferOptions -> digitalTransferOptions.getOnLines().stream())
                .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                .filter(onlineResource -> onlineResource.getProtocol().equals("OGC:STA"))
                .findFirst()
                ;
```

It returns a generic `Optional<? extends OnlineResource>` because of the `flatmap` method but I want it to return a `Optional<OnlineResource>`. How can I achieve that?

Comment: What's the problem with `Optional<? extends OnlineResource>`? You can use it just like `Optional<OnlineResource>` in most cases.

Comment: @Thomas Generic types are invariant, which is counter-intuitive for immutable collections (Optional is effectively a collection of length 1). `Optional<? extends OnlineResource>` is not assignable to `Optional<OnlineResource>`. There might be an interface that was too strictly defined which returns `Optional<OnlineResource>` or something. Just because there is nothing wrong with  `Optional<? extends OnlineResource>` in concept doesn't mean there is no reason to do what OP is asking

Comment: @Thomas not really. If you have, e.g. `Optional<? extends String> o;`, not even something as simple as `String s = o.orElse("");` works.

Comment: @Holger I see. Yes, `orElse()` and the like wouldn't work, that's why I added the "in most cases". I agree that having a `Optional<OnlineResource>` is preferable since optionals are immutable anyway. I just tried to raise awareness of "don't fix what doesn't need fixing", i.e. "I want to do X" isn't necessarily the same as "I need to do X (because of Y)" :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that either or both methods, `getTransferOptions()` and/or `getOnLines()` return a collection with a wildcard type, like `Collection<? extends …>`. This is [strongly discouraged](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/wildcardGuidelines.html):

> Using a wildcard as a return type should be avoided because it forces programmers using the code to deal with wildcards.

Which means precisely the problem you ran into. You should preferably fix these methods rather than the caller. If this is not possible, you may workaround the issue by specifying an explicit type for the `flatMap` operation instead of relying on type inference.

E.g., if you have code like

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
  Optional<? extends Number> result = Stream.of("")
      .flatMap(x -> method(x).stream())
      .filter(x -> true)
      .findFirst();
}

private static List<? extends Number> method(Object arg) {
    return Arrays.asList(42, 1.23);
}
```

change it to

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
  Optional<Number> result = Stream.of("")
      .<Number>flatMap(x -> method(x).stream())
      .filter(x -> true)
      .findFirst();
}

private static List<? extends Number> method(Object arg) {
    return Arrays.asList(42, 1.23);
}
```

to `flatMap` to a `Stream<Number>`, rather than `Stream<? extends Number>`. This works, because the `flatMap` has been declared as

```java
<R> Stream<R> flatMap(Function<? super T,? extends Stream<? extends R>> mapper)
```

allowing the specified function to return a stream of subtypes. This is an application of the [PECS rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/what-is-pecs-producer-extends-consumer-super).

---

But as said, it’s preferable to fix the collection returning methods. More than often, they also call methods following the PECS rule and hence, allow changing an element type from `? extends E` to `E`.

It might be helpful to know the following features:

If you already have an immutable collection like those created with `List.of(…)`, you can use methods `List.copyOf(…)` or `Set.copyOf(…)` to widen their element type without a copy.

```java
List<String> list1 = List.of("foo", "bar");

List<? extends Object> list2 = list1;

List<Object> list3 = List.copyOf(list2);

System.out.println(list1 == (Object)list3); // prints true
```

This works, because the immutability prevent callers from adding an `Object` to this `List<String>`. Likewise, you can create an unmodifiable *view* to any collection to avoid dealing with wildcard types:

```java
List<String> list1 = List.of("foo", "bar");

List<? extends Object> list2 = list1;

List<Object> list3 = Collections.unmodifiableList(list2);
```

This creates a new `List` instance, but without copying the contents, so it’s still cheap. But, as said, more than often, there are already methods involved which allow changing the type to the desired wildcard free type by just inserting the explicit type at an earlier point.

Comment: You have perfeclty identified my issue! Thanks for pointing me on PECS rule that I didn't know. I'm using this  [Apache SIS](https://sis.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/sis/metadata/iso/DefaultMetadata.html#getDistributionInfo()) library and `getDistributionInfo()` returns [this interface](http://www.geoapi.org/3.0/javadoc/org/opengis/metadata/distribution/Distribution.html). Should Apache SIS implement the interface in order to avoid the cast?

Comment: The only useful scenario would be that there are public implementations supposed to override the methods to return a collection of a more specific concrete type, like with `interface I { Collection<? extends Number> get(); } public class Concrete implements I {@Override public Collection<Integer> get() { … }}` But since I don’t see public implementations in this documentation, there probably shouldn’t be wildcards in the return types.

Answer (score 1):

Add a cast. It's safe, since all `? extends X`s are necessarily `X`s.

```
Optional<Number> foo = Optional.of("ABC")
    .flatMap(Main::length); // Does not compile

Optional<Number> bar = Optional.of("DEFG")
    .flatMap(Main::length)
    .map(Number.class::cast); // Safe
```

```
private static Optional<? extends Number> length(String str) {
    return Optional.ofNullable(str).map(String::length);
}
```

Comment: The cast is obsolete. Even `Optional<Number> bar = Optional.of("DEFG") .flatMap(Main::length) .map(Function.identity());` does the job. But since this question is about `Stream.flatMap` rather than `Optional.flatMap`, you don’t need a conversion step at all.

Comment: @Holger I think we have different definitions of obsolete. Yes, there are other ways to achieve the same thing, but so what? That's any high level language for you. Arguably, your version is less clear because mapping to identity should in theory be useless (and I wouldn't be surprised if static analysis would give false positives about it). At least with a cast, the intent of fixing a type system issue is clear.

Comment: Why should a static analysis brag about an apparently useless `map` step but not about an obviously useless cast (of a `Number` to a `Number`)? Since you could chain a `.map(Number.class::cast)` to any optional, including those that would always fail, e.g. `Optional.of("string").map(Number.class::cast)`, it is *not* obvious to the reader that this specific case is a cast that will always succeed. In contrast, the compiler will accept `.map(Function.identity())` only if the operation will always succeed.

Comment: @Holger The whole point of a cast is a programmer declaring "*I know more than the type system in this instance*". It's very rare that static analysis can prove that it's redundant, except trivial cases. In any case, it's clearly not "obsolete". There are pros and cons to both. We are back around to "there are multiple ways to achieve the same goal in high level languages", and once again, the question is "so what?"